# Display error if no input like a floating point number is done in a TextBox

Tags: c#

I am creating a basic server downtime calculator app in a Visual Studio project where I have to create a 2D array that lets me store the total server downtime and take the average. Whenever I tried to debug the Form where I don't enter floating point numbers, the app would crash and the error "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'" is displayed.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    float[] numberInsert = new float[5];
    float sum = 0; //Set initial value to 0 to begin calculation
    float average = 0; //Set initial values for sum and average to 0 to begin calculation
    bool isNumber = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void createDowntimeArray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtDowntime1.Text))
        {
            //DisplayAlert("Error!", "Please type in a valid number.", "");
            Console.WriteLine("Please type in a valid number!");
            //isNumber = true;
        }
        else
        {

            //MessageBox.Show("Empty Text Field.");
        }

        numberInsert[0] = float.Parse(txtDowntime1.Text);
        numberInsert[1] = float.Parse(txtDowntime2.Text);
        numberInsert[2] = float.Parse(txtDowntime3.Text);
        numberInsert[3] = float.Parse(txtDowntime4.Text);
        numberInsert[4] = float.Parse(txtDowntime5.Text);


        for (int i = 0; i <= numberInsert.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            sum += numberInsert[i]; //Shows sum of floats added up
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Total : " + sum.ToString());
    }
```

I tried changing the if-else statement to mention one of the textboxes' name property "txtDowntime1.Text" whether if there is no text inputted. I tried moving the if-else statement above and beneath the assigned array data.

Comment: Float.TryParse is what you need

Comment: you can check if number can be parsed to float with `float.TryParse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `createDowntimeArray_Click()` method to

```
private void createDowntimeArray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!ValuesValid())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("One or more fields contain invalid number.");
        return;
    }
    numberInsert[0] = float.Parse(txtDowntime1.Text);
    numberInsert[1] = float.Parse(txtDowntime2.Text);
    numberInsert[2] = float.Parse(txtDowntime3.Text);
    numberInsert[3] = float.Parse(txtDowntime4.Text);
    numberInsert[4] = float.Parse(txtDowntime5.Text);

    for (int i = 0; i <= numberInsert.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        sum += numberInsert[i]; //Shows sum of floats added up
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Total : " + sum.ToString());
}
```

and use the following helper method:

```
private bool ValuesValid()
{
    return float.TryParse(txtDowntime1.Text, out _) &&
        float.TryParse(txtDowntime2.Text, out _) &&
        float.TryParse(txtDowntime3.Text, out _) &&
        float.TryParse(txtDowntime4.Text, out _) &&
        float.TryParse(txtDowntime5.Text, out _);
}
```

Note that `float.Parse()` method throws `FormatException` when the input does not represent a number in a valid format. So use `float.TryParse()` method to check the validity of your input, which does not throw exception with invalid input.

Comment: Thanks! That helps. In addition, I need to individually check if no or any has been made in these textboxes.

Comment: Yes, it will be better to check the inputs individually and spot the exact fields including the invalid entry for the convenience of the user. My answer is just a quick solution.